# Database versioning when testing layered design

Tags: database, testing, development-process, versioning, project-structure

Let's say there are two layers of an application:

1. *Business logic layer*
2. *Data access layer*

Assume integration tests need to be written also for the *Business logic layer*. Alas tests that run against the database.

Let's also say you are implementing features in a branch in the *Data access layer* and in this branch you commit (git) some sql-scripts for restructuring your database (e.g. adding some columns). These scripts are run before the CI-tests to make your integration tests able to work against the new db structure. **Edit:** *Also the database is lightweight and a new one is spun up each time the tests are run. The database is not shared.*

Now assume you publish a dev-version of your *Data access layer* and use that as a dependency when developing something in the *Business logic layer* in order to use these new features.

> **How would you design and structure your projects and versioning**
> **control system in order to update the database that the CI-tests of**
> **the *Business logic layer* run against during development?**

Comment: Do you have a lightweight DB system for testing where you can quickly spin up a new  individual instance for each new test run?

Comment: In addition to @DocBrown question. Does `database that the CI-tests of the Business logic layer run against` has any sort of concurrency? Is it a shared resource? Any other application or CI pipeline backed by this database?

Comment: @DocBrown Yes it is lightweight and that's how it is done - a new individual instance is spun up for each new test run. The database is basically empty but the tests commit their changes after each run if that is of importance.

Comment: @Laiv It is not a shared resource, the db solely exists for the specific test run.
Edited question as well according to yours and DocBrown's question.